# How to verify my domain with Apple in a React App

Tags: reactjs, applepay

Does someone know how to verify a domain with Apple using React.js at the url mydomain.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt

I tried to create the .well-known folder in public folder and put the apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt file inside. I'm able to access the file (just access, not download) but the verification still fail on Apple website. Does someone has an other solution ?

I also made a custom route like this

```
<Route path="/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt" render={() => (
                                    <link rel="apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt file" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt" />
                                )}
```

Comment: did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 7):

What I did on my react app, hosted on heroku with Stripe (which provides Apple Pay) :

1. In ./client : Create an "applepay" directory and copy/past the "apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association" file.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMXD1.png)

2. In your client package.json file, find the "scripts" list, where you should at least read `"build": "react-scripts build"`.
   Add `"mkdir -p ./build/.well-known && cp ./applepay/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association ./build/.well-known/"`.
   It will create during the build an new directory (mkdir) and copy (cp) the verification file inside it.

```
"scripts": {
    ...,
    "build": "react-scripts build && mkdir -p ./build/.well-known && cp ./applepay/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association ./build/.well-known/",
    ...,
},
```

3. Push online your updated code, make sure it is an httpS domain, your apple pay merchant id file should be detected.
   If you use Stripe you'll get :

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCu4I.png)

I hope it helped!

Comment: Not sure why this isn't marked as the correct answer. Helped me a ton, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make one directory in public directory of you repo.
With name ".well-known" then add the "apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association" file inside it.
This file is accessible then.

public > .well-known > apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association

Comment: yes this is the answer, the other answer is crazy

Comment: This is the answer for anyone not redirecting users on a 404 error. But for anyone using `react-router-dom` and redirecting unknown routes to a custom 404/Not Found Route, they'll need to set a new redirect/rewrite rule in their hosting configuration (e.g., AWS Amplify). See [this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320954/how-to-verify-my-stripe-domain-for-apple-pay-with-react-on-aws-amplify)