# How to verify my Stripe domain for Apple Pay with React on AWS Amplify?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, aws-amplify, applepay

I am using AWS Amplify to host my React application and I want to add Apple Pay. To do this, I need to verify my domain through Stripe by uploading a file to the path: `<domain>.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`

What are the steps to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a few days trying to figure this out. Here's the final solution that worked for me:

1. Put the file `apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association` in a new folder called `.well-known` in your `public` folder. The path should now be `public/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`.
2. Change the extension of the file to .json -> `apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.json`
3. Go to the AWS Console and to your Amplify project's Rewrites and Redirects
4. Add the following rule as **the top rule. There should be no rule above it!**

```
{
    "source": "/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association",
    "target": "/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.json",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go for anyone using `react-router-dom` and redirecting unknown routes to a custom 404/Not Found Route. FWIW, changing the extension was necessary for me (I used .txt because my linter threw a fit about that file not being valid json) -- beyond just putting the file in public/.well-known/ . Without giving the file an extension AND making this as the _top rule_ in Amplify, verification wouldn't work since it would get redirected to the 404 route.